# Prevent window.scroll handler from persisting to other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function for infinite-scrolling on my pages. It seems like once I go to a page with that triggers the if statement, every page I go to after that will continue to trigger the scroll handler. I know this because every other page prints 'window scroll' to the console every time I scroll but does not trigger 'if statement true'. How do I make it so the window.scroll only works on a page with `#infinite-scrolling`?

```
function initPagination() {
  var paginate = function(buttonPress) {
    var url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');

    if (buttonPress || (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60)) {
      // TODO - Removing this line was causing duplicates to load so it's worth investigating the cause
      $('.pagination').html('Please Wait...');
      return $.getScript(url);
    }
  };

  if ($('#infinite-scrolling').length) {
    console.log('if statement true');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      console.log('window scroll');
      paginate(false);
    });
    return $(window).scroll();
  }

  $('#infinite-scrolling-button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).html('Loading...');
    paginate(true);
    $(this).html('Load more');
  });
}
```

Edit: Part of the problem might be related to turbolinks. When I refresh a page the scroll handler doesn't seem to trigger anymore.

Comment: Turbolinks injects the page into `<body>`, which means all event listeners persist.

Comment: @ChrisG so sounds like the issue is with turbolinks. How can I work around that? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The window scroll event listener is getting set when you want the page to auto-scroll, but it is not getting unset when the page changes due to the behavior of turbolinks. Try using `$(window).unbind("scroll");` to get rid of the scroll event whenever a new page loads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where should I put this code? Can I put it somewhere in my function? Or do I need to put it in some sort of function that triggers every time a new page loads?

Comment: You could put it inside the `initPagination()` function if that function runs whenever a link is clicked. Otherwise you will need to put it in a function that triggers whenever a new page loads.